# "No overload matches this call." while calling an AsyncThunk function (redux toolkit)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I have an issue with the following `createAsyncThunk` method :

```
export const fetchPatientByDocument = createAsyncThunk<
  Patient,
  string,
  { state: { patient: { loading: string; CurrentRequestId: string } } }
>(
  'patient/fetchByDocument',
  async (patientdocument: string, { getState, requestId }) => {
    const { CurrentRequestId, loading } = getState().patient;
    if (loading !== 'pending' || requestId !== CurrentRequestId) {
      return;
    }
    const RequestURL: string =
      PatientBaseUrl + 'Pacientes/3/' + patientdocument;

    const response = await fetch(RequestURL).then((data) => data.json());

    return response;
  }
);
```

There is no problem here, but when I try to `dispatch` this function from the login page,

```
  const handlerButtonclick = () => {
    const { loading, CurrentRequestId } = CurrentPatient;

    if (patientDocument) {
      const fetchPatient = async (patientDocument: string) => {
        try {
          const patient = await dispatch(
            fetchPatientByDocument(patientDocument)
          );
        } catch (e) {
          throw e;
        }
      };
    }

    // navigate(patientDocument + '/verification');
  };
```

I get this error :

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 3, '(thunkAction: ThunkAction<Promise<PayloadAction<Patient, string, { arg: string; requestId: string; requestStatus: "fulfilled"; }, never> | PayloadAction<unknown, string, { arg: string; requestId: string; requestStatus: "rejected"; aborted: boolean; condition: boolean; } & ({ ...; } | ({ ...; } & {})), SerializedError>> & { ...; }, CombinedState<...>, undefined, AnyAction>): Promise<...> & { ...; }', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<Patient, string, { state: { patient: { loading: string; CurrentRequestId: string; }; }; dispatch?: Dispatch<AnyAction> | undefined; extra?: unknown; rejectValue?: unknown; serializedErrorType?: unknown; pendingMeta?: unknown; fulfilledMeta?: unknown; rejectedMeta?: unknown; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ThunkAction<Promise<PayloadAction<Patient, string, { arg: string; requestId: string; requestStatus: "fulfilled"; }, never> | PayloadAction<unknown, string, { arg: string; requestId: string; requestStatus: "rejected"; aborted: boolean; condition: boolean; } & ({ ...; } | ({ ...; } & {})), SerializedError>> & { ...; }...'.
> Types of parameters 'getState' and 'getState' are incompatible.
> Call signature return types 'CombinedState<{ router: RouterState<any>; patient: PatientState; }>' and '{ patient: { loading: string; CurrentRequestId: string; }; }' are incompatible.
> The types of 'patient.CurrentRequestId' are incompatible between these types.
> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Overload 2 of 3, '(action: AnyAction): AnyAction', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<Patient, string, { state: { patient: { loading: string; CurrentRequestId: string; }; }; dispatch?: Dispatch<AnyAction> | undefined; extra?: unknown; rejectValue?: unknown; serializedErrorType?: unknown; pendingMeta?: unknown; fulfilledMeta?: unknown; rejectedMeta?: unknown; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
> Property 'type' is missing in type 'AsyncThunkAction<Patient, string, { state: { patient: { loading: string; CurrentRequestId: string; }; }; dispatch?: Dispatch<AnyAction> | undefined; extra?: unknown; rejectValue?: unknown; serializedErrorType?: unknown; pendingMeta?: unknown; fulfilledMeta?: unknown; rejectedMeta?: unknown; }>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.
> Overload 3 of 3, '(action: AnyAction | ThunkAction<Promise<PayloadAction<Patient, string, { arg: string; requestId: string; requestStatus: "fulfilled"; }, never> | PayloadAction<unknown, string, { ...; } & ({ ...; } | ({ ...; } & {})), SerializedError>> & { ...; }, CombinedState<...>, undefined, AnyAction>): AnyAction | (Promise<...> & { ...; })', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<Patient, string, { state: { patient: { loading: string; CurrentRequestId: string; }; }; dispatch?: Dispatch<AnyAction> | undefined; extra?: unknown; rejectValue?: unknown; serializedErrorType?: unknown; pendingMeta?: unknown; fulfilledMeta?: unknown; rejectedMeta?: unknown; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction | ThunkAction<Promise<PayloadAction<Patient, string, { arg: string; requestId: string; requestStatus: "fulfilled"; }, never> | PayloadAction<unknown, string, {
> ...; } & ({ ...; } | ({ ...; } & {})), SerializedError>> & { ...; }, CombinedState<...>, undefined, AnyAction>'.
> Type 'AsyncThunkAction<Patient, string, { state: { patient: { loading: string; CurrentRequestId: string; }; }; dispatch?: Dispatch<AnyAction> | undefined; extra?: unknown; rejectValue?: unknown; serializedErrorType?: unknown; pendingMeta?: unknown; fulfilledMeta?: unknown; rejectedMeta?: unknown; }>' is not assignable to type 'ThunkAction<Promise<PayloadAction<Patient, string, { arg: string; requestId: string; requestStatus: "fulfilled"; }, never> | PayloadAction<unknown, string, { arg: string; requestId: string; requestStatus: "rejected"; aborted: boolean; condition: boolean; } & ({ ...; } | ({ ...; } & {})), SerializedError>> & { ...; }...'.

I already tried to pass the `state` in the `fetchPatientByDocument` call, or remove it from `createAsyncThunk` but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your hand-written override of the `state` generic for `createAsyncThunk` does not match the actual root state type for the entire app.

The right approach here is to follow our TS usage guidelines to infer a `RootState` type for the *entire* app state, and use that:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types
- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#typing-the-thunkapi-object

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @markerikson, I wasn't setting correctly the `state and dispatch's` types in the `createAsyncThunk` definition. This worked for me in case it can help some soul :

```
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from '../store';

export const fetchPatientByDocument = createAsyncThunk<
  Patient,
  string,
  {
    // Optional fields for defining thunkApi field types
    dispatch: AppDispatch;
    state: RootState;
    extraArguemnt: {
      loading: string;
      CurrentRequestId: string | undefined;
    };
  }
>(
  'patient/fetchByDocument',
  async (patientdocument: string, { getState, requestId }) => {
    const { CurrentRequestId, loading } = getState().patient;
    if (loading !== 'pending' || requestId !== CurrentRequestId) {
      return;
    }
    const RequestURL: string =
      PatientBaseUrl + 'Pacientes/3/' + patientdocument;

    const response = await fetch(RequestURL).then((data) => data.json());

    return response;
  }
);
```

And the `store.js` file :

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import PatientReducer from '../reducer/patientSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    patient: PatientReducer
  }
});
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

Thank you very much!